# cannot select children elements of a specific class

Tags: jquery

Why this doesn't work

```
<div class='folder lev1'>323</div>
<div class='folder lev2'>525</div>
<div class='file lev3'>727</div>
<div class='file lev3'>929</div>
<div class='folder lev1'>end</div>
```

js

```
$(".lev1").click(function(){
    if ($(this).next().is(":visible")) {
        $(this).nextUntil(".lev1").hide(); // works
    }
    else {
        $(this).children(".lev2").show();  // doesn't work
        $(this).find(".lev2").show();  // also tried - doesn't work
        console.log("323"); // works
    }
});
```

Console is without errors.

Comment: consider my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, .lev1 doesn't have any chlidren. has siblings.

```
$(".lev1").click(function(){
    if ($(this).next().is(":visible")) {
        $(this).nextUntil(".lev1").hide(); // works
    }
    else {
        $(this).siblings(".lev2").show();  // works
    }
});
```

Or, if you want the next .lev2 be shown:

```
$(".lev1").click(function(){
    if ($(this).next().is(":visible")) {
        $(this).nextUntil(".lev1").hide(); // works
    }
    else {
        $(this).nextAll(".lev2").show();  // works
    }
});
```